# Aggregate functions based on specific datetime values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset with dated entries/exits per hour for different train stations. One of the problems is that some of the operating hours of the train stations cause irregular intervals in the time increments (i.e. some trains close at 5:30pm, so some rows will have an odd timestamp of 05:30:00, while all other rows do not have any values in the minute portion of the timestamp).

I want to standardize the data to hourly intervals and would like to collapse some of these irregular 30minute timestamps (so any entries/exits for a station at the timestamp 05:30:00 should be summed with the entries/exits at timestamp 05:00:00).

Is there a way to use groupby/aggregate functions to execute this?

Provided below is a sample dataframe, along with the final result I am looking to achieve:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date Time':pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 00:30:00', 
                                                '2023-01-01 00:30:00', '2023-01-01 00:30:00',  '2023-01-01 01:00:00', 
                                                '2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00']),
     'Station':['Station A', 'Station B', 'Station C', 'Station A', 'Station B', 'Station C','Station A', 'Station B', 'Station C'],
     'Entries':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'Exits':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]}
)
```

Output:

| Date Time | Station | Entries | Exits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |

Desired Output:

| Date Time | Station | Entries | Exits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station A | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station B | 4 | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station C | 6 | 6 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Can you groupby the date, hour, and station? e.g. `df.groupby([df["Date Time"].dt.date, df["Date Time"].dt.hour, "Station"]).sum()`

Comment: @jqurious that does work creating a multi-index dataframe! But when i use .reset_index() to reset to a single index dataframe, I get the error "ValueError: cannot insert ID, already exists". If I use .reset_index(drop = True) then I have the issue of having the Date Time and Station values being removed from the dataframe entirely. Is there a simple way to convert the multi-index dataframe from the groupby into a single index while preserving the Date Time and Station columns?

Comment: You can use `.agg()` - I've added an answer showing how. It was too large to use in a comment so I just used `.sum()` here as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly group on just the relevant parts of the `Date Time` column - in this case the `dt.date` and `dt.hour`.

`first` can be used for the "non-summed" columns inside the aggregation.

```
# group by date, hour, and station name

groups = [
   df["Date Time"].dt.date, df["Date Time"].dt.hour, "Station"
]

(df.groupby(groups, as_index=False)
   .agg({
      "Date Time": "first",
      "Station": "first",
      "Entries": sum,
      "Exits": sum,
    })
 )
```

```
            Date Time    Station  Entries  Exits
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00  Station A        2      2
1 2023-01-01 00:00:00  Station B        4      4
2 2023-01-01 00:00:00  Station C        6      6
3 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Station A        1      1
4 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Station B        2      2
5 2023-01-01 01:00:00  Station C        3      3
```

Comment: You can avoid `.reset_index(drop=True)` by setting `as_index=False` in the `.groupby`

Comment: Thanks @IanThompson - I'll use that instead.